# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide2' while trying to use poetry env

Tags: python, anaconda, python-poetry, anaconda3

i'm trying to use slicereg (https://github.com/brainglobe/slicereg) for data registration.

after import code from github page and install poetry to run slicereg i keep getting the following error :

```
The virtual environment found in ~\.conda\envs\sliceregenv seems to be broken.
Recreating virtualenv slicereg-6kSWvOuc-py3.8 in ~\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\slicereg-6kSWvOuc-py3.8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "~\.conda\envs\sliceregenv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "~\slicereg\slicereg\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide2'
```

Pyside2 is already installed in my env using pip.
Any advice on how to resolve this issue ?

Thx

Comment: Can you provide how you set up your env? I see that venv name is different from the project's documentation

Comment: I follow the github indications to setup the env with python 3.8 version. i tried multiple ways to setup the env ending every times with the same error.

Comment: Are you using raw Windows or WSL?

Comment: i'm using Windows 10

Comment: Ok! Can you share the outputs for: `where pip`, `where python`, and `where poetry`?

Comment: Ok, my guess was not right. Can you please recreate this venv (as it seems to be broken, by the error message)? `conda env remove -n sliceregenv`, create the environment again, and then redo the README steps. At the end of the instructions, install pyside2 with conda: `conda install -c conda-forge pyside2`.

Comment: Using conda to install pyside2 : virtual env is still broken + got ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide2' error again

Comment: Are you creating a venv before running `poetry install`?

Comment: Yes sir , i can't understand why my env seems to be broken from the start aswell

Comment: You should not create an env before run `poetry install`. Poetry takes care of creating a sort of venv. Running it from inside a venv can cause conflicts (what could be happening here). Try running `poetry install` from "outside" your venv. You'll probably need: `sudo apt-get install python3.8-venv` if poetry cant find python 3.8. Alternatively, you can run: `poetry config virtualenvs.create false` from inside your venv before running `poetry install`.

Comment: in any way i setup poetry and my conda env i still getting Pyside2 error.

Comment: I think you are hit by https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4566

Comment: thx i will watch closer that link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an issue, poetry fails to recognize conda environments as valid

see more at https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4566

Remain unresolved for the current release (1.1.12)

Update : https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/5907